# GOES Interview at Chicago-O'Hare

Tags: customs-and-immigration, trusted-traveler

Anyone go through the [Global Online Enrollment System](https://goes-app.cbp.dhs.gov/main/goes) interview process at Chicago-O'Hare recently?  How was the wait?

Comment: there are no wait times normally, in all centers. That's why they give appointments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an appointment and did not wait at all.  Just walked right up.

They pretty much ask you the same questions that are in the online application, unless they see a reason to ask more.

It was very fast.  Fast enough that I made it in and out within the free short-term parking window.